# Mathematical definition of G1 boundary conditions

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I am looking for a mathematical descrition of a surface generation problem.

During my literature research I found out that I might look for the solution of a surface optimisation problem like the plateau problem under boundary conditions that might be called $G1$ boundary conditions.

Can anyone give me some literature advice how G1 boundary conditions are defined mathematically?

Comment: Something that sounds similar and often appears in PDEs etc.: Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary. That means that your boundary should be a $C^1$-differentiable submanifold of that subset (or more general of your manifold, if that problem is given in that context).

Comment: I am not interessted in the shape of the boundary but in small neighborhoods of every point on the boundary there should exist charts of a 2 dimensional $C^1$-manifold